# many to many Relationship Data fetching

Tags: python, django

I have two models(columns) with many to many relations.

```
class ClinicHospital(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    address = models.TextField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("clinichospital_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Doctor(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    clinic_hospital = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicHospital)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to fetch all `ClinicHospital` which is associated with a specific Doctor.
here is my view.py

```
class DoctorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Doctor

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context[ClinicHospital] = ClinicHospital.objects.all()
        return context
```

and it is my HTML page

```
{% for clinic in doctor_detail %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{clinic.name}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current doctor instance by [**`self.get_object()`**--(Django Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) and associated clinics by **`self.get_object().clinic_hospital.all()`**. So, pass that QuerySet to template through context

```
class DoctorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Doctor

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['clinic_hospital_list'] = self.get_object().clinic_hospital.all()
        return context
```

and change your template accordingly

```
{% for clinic in clinic_hospital_list %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{clinic.name}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can filter in reverse manner also, i.e 

ClinicHospital.objects.filter(doctor=self.get_object())

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, I'm in trouble to delete value from intermediate table of specific Doctor

Comment: You should ask a new question regarding your new issue.